# How do I return a SYS_REFCURSOR from a stored procedure after a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I am a bit new to Oracle and PL SQL. I have a procedure like the following.

```
{
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure (MyRecordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE

        CURSOR MyRecordset IS 
        select
        ...
        from table1, table2, etc..

    BEGIN
        FOR Record in MyRecordset
        LOOP        
            --Do something                             
        END LOOP; -- IMPLICIT CLOSE OCCURS
        -- THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO RETURN THE CURSOR. DOES THIS NOT OPEN IT AT BEGINNING AGAIN?
        OPEN MyRecordset;
    END;
END MyProcedure;
/
}
```

I need to return a SYS_REFCURSOR. Is this sufficient? When I try to test it with the following in Toad I get no output in the data grid.

```
{
DECLARE
 type result_set is ref cursor; 
BEGIN
 BIZTALK.GetCustomerPaymentsDebug(:result_set);
END;
}
```

Comment: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

Comment: Why do you want to iterate through the results in your procedure and then re-execute the query, potentially returning different results now, and return that to the caller?  Every time I've seen someone want to do that sort of thing, they've been missing the fact that the results may be different or they're trying to do something in the procedure that ought to be done in the client and still realistically needs to be done in the client anyway.

Comment: Well, actually that is the problem I am trying to solve! I need to do an insert and update on another table based on the result set. The only other way I have been able to do this is with another select, which could theoretically return a different result set. But I guess this would be the same according to you comments:-(

Comment: I thought the cursor result was in memory and would not change if I simply reopened the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

This example works for me. I think it should help you.

```
 
Declare cursor like:
 TYPE genCurType IS REF CURSOR;
```

PROCEDURE return_in
 (  p_ime           IN     VARCHAR2
  , po_seznam       OUT    genCurType
  , po_errid        OUT    errorIdType
  , po_errmsg       OUT    errorMsgType
  )
IS
 cc_module_name CONSTANT  VARCHAR2(60):= 'return_ins';
BEGIN
        OPEN po_seznam   FOR SELECT IME, OPIS, NAZIV, OBRAZEC
                             FROM test
                             WHERE upper(IME) = upper(p_ime);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
        po_errid := SQLCODE;
        po_errmsg := 'Poizvedba ni bila uspešna! ('||SQLERRM||''||gc_package||'.'||cc_module_name||')';

END;